# How can I catch an rtmp url the same way I do with http?

Tags: firefox, rtmp, try-catch

I'd like to monitorize rtmp connections the same way I do with http

In firefox for example

Thank You!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark?

http://www.wireshark.org/